# What is wrong with this Java code

Tags: java

This is my add method for my Josephus class in which I am supposed to be using a Circular Linked List. I am getting null pointer exceptions in a few areas in my class but it is all because of this method. Can anyone see any OBVIOUS mistakes from looking at this code?

```
/** Inserts the specified element in the list at the
     last position
     @param dataItem the element to add
   */
 // Complexity O(1)
 @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
public void add(E dataItem) {
    Node <E> node = new Node <E> (dataItem,null,null);
    if (count == 0){ // list is empty
        head = node.previous= node;  
    }

    else {
       head.previous.next = node;
       node.previous = head.previous;
       head.previous = node;
    }
    count++; 
    }
```

Full code: http://pastebin.com/k4Hmbqmw

Comment: There are to much unknown variables. So it is very head th see the problem.

Comment: Did you use curly braces in the else part?

Comment: The big thing is you are missing `{ }` around the if and else blocks.

Comment: From the indentation of your code posted in the link it looks like `count++` might not be intended to be included in the curly braces of the else branch.

Comment: Please check my fixed code...I just edited. I also posted full code.

Comment: I am getting NullPointerExceptions that all trace back to the add method here...

Comment: If you edit the code in your question, the answers won't match any more...

Comment: Katja, this new edited code was actually my original code...i just realized i accidentally didnt include the curly braces earlier when i was coding but fixed it and posted the earlier code by accident. so as you can see, here is my new code so none of the answers given here apply now. i am gettin nullpointerexceptions stemming from add method, i have posted full code in pastebin link for people to view and help me because i am stuck.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you need to enclose your `else` section in curly braces:

```
public void add(E dataItem) {
    Node <E> node = new Node <E> (dataItem, null, null);
    if (count == 0) { // list is empty
        head = node.previous= node ;  
    } else {
       (head.previous).next = node;
       node.previous = head.previous;
       head.previous = node;
    }
    count++;
}
```

Otherwise, the last three lines are executed every time instead of just the last one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have curly braces around the if/else blocks